# Should we tolerate questions relating to software development?

Tags: discussion

I'm seeing quite a few questions that are specifically asking about interacting with video in a programmatic manner. Not just ffmpeg command line stuff but also actual programming with video software libraries.

My first thought is to always move these questions to Stackoverflow but then I also thought that it might be actually not so bad to at least allow them to be asked here. We might not have the user base yet to cover these questions very well but in a broader sense I do think that these questions relate to modern video production.

Maybe not in the "creative" way but engineers who are building pipelines or even video generalists who seek workflow automation will usually want experience from people who work in the video production industry and not strict programmers who often have very little experience with video production.

Again I don't see we have too many people who fit that bill here yet but I don't think that alone is a good reason to not at least allow that type of questions.

What I would refrain from is to allow any kind of video playback questions that often get asked here like "how can I put a video on my blog/website, what library/code do I need?". Anything that isn't useful in the creation process of a video.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, my feeling is that Stack Overflow is a better place for programming questions.  We don't take bulletin board programming questions on Community Management, I don't see how programming questions about video stuff is any different.  They aren't dealing with creating video, they are dealing with creating tools to create video.  It is no more on topic than asking about how to build a CMOS sensor for a video camera.

Comment: Thats a valid point. I do feel that CMOS sensors are a different league but I get your point :)
I just had the experience that these kind of things were actually tasks in the daily work of especially smaller video production companies where the individual had a tremendous workload so having/making tools/scripts that take away some repetitive manual work was always very welcome.

Comment: @PTS yeah, there's a fine line difference between macro/scripting and software development though.  I'm not sure exactly where the line is, but if you are actually writing a stand alone program, I think the question at that point is about writing a program that happens to be useful in your video stuff, where as scripting a command line tool may or may not be still within scope depending on how useful it is.  I'm not sure how to draw that line, but I'm pretty sure that compiling your own programs is far to the software dev side of it.